# Open Files from mail

Tags: file, email, ios5

I'm struggling with file handling on iOS.
I could already assign my file type to iOS and I can launch my app from mail with a special file.
My app is launching and I'm firing this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if([url isFileURL])
    {
        NSString *fileConts = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        [self.viewController openFile:fileConts];
        fileConts = nil;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The `openFile:(NSString)` method is declared in the viewController and sets the value of a textView (for now). This method works fine. I tested it via `[self.viewController openFile:@"test"];`.

But when my application launches with file attached, the textView keeps empty.
It seems that it doesn't adopt the string value or that it can't read the string value.

Comment: why are you passing `nil` for the error param in your `initWithContentsOfFile` method?  there may be a useful hint to your problem being returned in a error.  Also, does `fileConts` have any length or content before you go into your `openFile` method?

Comment: Thanks for the error tip… I printed the error and it says that the file can't be found. I followed the path and found the file. So the given URL is correct but the app can't find the file. Any suggestions?

Comment: I could solve all my problems. I just hat to `NSString *fileConts = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];` using url instead of NSString. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem.
My mistake was to `initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)`

I updated my code with
`NSString *fileConts = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];`

Now I'm happy!
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

handleOpenURL will be called only if application already running (in the background).

To make sure you correctly dispatch incoming files, you also need to check it on the app launch:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
// Process url here
}
```

It's good idea to have 1 URL dispatcher called both from handleOpenURL and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: This is not right. I tested some code that calls my method on didFinishLaunching. But then my method gets fired twice. So it turned out that `handleOpenFile` is called even when the app is not in background.